# Re-Open/Throw Error for OLE DB Connection Timeout

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, insert, oledb

I built an app in VS where users can import call evaluations (written in vb.net). However, users continue to leave the application open all day and it appears at some point the OLE DB connection is timing out and not submitting records.

In my insert function I have:

```
 Try
conn.ConnectionString = myconnection
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    conn.Open()
End If
    Dim myquery As String = "insert into ..."
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
With cmd
''more insert
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
conn.Close()
```

then on my import button I have an if statement to check for blank fields and elseif statement to perform the insert function

any ideas to check for a closed connection and if not open it? Or, any ideas on putting a timer that displays a message the connection has timed out?

any help is appreciated!

**Update Question**

Should I be doing a try catch with the connection itself and then the insert function?

ie:

```
 Try
    cnn = New OleDbConnection()
    cnn.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
Dim myquery As String = "insert into ..."
```

Comment: Create, use and then close and dispose connections as needed.

Comment: Have you considered writing a function that tests the connection by doing something harmless that should succeed if it was still good, and catches an appropriate exception in the case that it wasn't good?

Comment: Ian, that's definitely an idea!

Comment: Plutonix, what do you mean of by dispose? I appear to be opening, using, and closing unless I am missing something

Comment: Could the time-out be caused by network congestion or perhaps too great server load?